# Interpreting Y Outcome Variable when primary X is a proportion/ratio

Tags: regression, interpretation

I am currently starting with a simple regression whereas my outcome Y= raw student scores in an exam, while my X variable of interest is the ratio of substitute teachers in the school.

I would truly appreciate your support interpreting the results:

My code:

```
## Run a simple regression on Y= achievement_scientific_exam ratio of substitute teachers 

fit <- lm(achievement_scientific_male ~ ratio_sub_teachers, data=y_continuous_regression)
summary(fit) # show results

#Other useful functions
coefficients(fit) # model coefficients
confint(fit, level=0.95) # CIs for model parameters
#fitted(fit) # predicted values
```

```
My regression results are as follows:
Call:
lm(formula = achievement_scientific_male ~ ratio_sub_teachers, 
    data = y_continuous_regression)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-20.774  -7.071  -1.999   6.694  24.441 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         65.9915     0.1524  433.04   <2e-16 ***
ratio_sub_teachers  -2.1068     0.2211   -9.53   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.802 on 17397 degrees of freedom
  (85795 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.005194,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.005136 
F-statistic: 90.82 on 1 and 17397 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

       (Intercept) ratio_sub_teachers 
          65.99151           -2.10683 
                       2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)        65.692807 66.290218
ratio_sub_teachers -2.540147 -1.673514
```

Comment: Well, for one, you are excluding 85,795 of your observations (83%) due to missing data. Secondly, *ratio_sub_teachers* alone is explaining very little of the variation in *achievement_scientific_male*.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are more likely to get meaningful answers if you could provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It is very helpful to see the data you are operating on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intercept (65.99) can be interpreted as follows: when your X variable (ratio of substitute teachers) is 0, your model will predict that student scores will be 65,99.

The coefficient of your X (-2.1068) tells you, that for every one increase of your X value, your predicted Y value will drop with -2.1068.

The models is thus: Y = 65,99 - 2,1068X

If X = 0 then predicted Y = 65,99
If X = 1 then predicted Y = 63,8832
If X = 10 then predicted Y = 44,992

However it's obvious that there are many other variables have an influence on the test score, but they are not taking into account in your model. You can also see this in your output due to your low R-squared.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback!
Just to clarify, my x is expressed as a proportion or ratio, so when you say that X = 1, do you mean .01 or 1 as in 100%?

Comment: Here I assumed you took percentages as X = 1 (1%), X = 2 (2%). If that's the case than an increase of one from 1% to 2% would decrease your Y with 2.1068. However when your data is X = 0.01 (1%) than an increase of 1 would be 1.01 (101%) which is not possible. The interpretation than would be, for every percentage increase X = 0.01 to X = 0.02 (1% to 2%) your Y would decrease with 2.1068*0.01

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it!